# Bigquery - Data Validation in custom field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have data in below format. I need to run a rule as below -
If column A contains value 15, it should be flagged as Valid, else it should be flagged as Invalid

Below is my Input and expected Output data

**Input Data**

```
Key | Value     
----|-----------
1221|10,15,23,33
1123|10,11,12
1990|19,15
1000|null
```

Below is my expected output

```
Key | Value     | Validation Result|
----|-----------|------------------|
1221|10,15,23,33|             Valid|
1123|10,11,12   |           Invalid|
1990|19,15      |             Valid|
1000|null       |           Invalid|
------------------------------------
```

I did try something with the split function, but it just splits into multiple rows, looking for something without splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select *,
  if('15' in unnest(split(value)), 'valid', 'invalid') IsValid
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This works. Just another clarification. What if I had a different delimiter? Like 10;15;23;33. I don't see any specification of a delimiter in your query. How does it understand that values are separated by comma ?

Comment: Split function has second optional argument, which is by default is comma, but you can set it as you wish